# find certain words in file python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file(test.txt) and content is as follows:

```
I0914 17:37:15.763941 29832 abc.cpp:138] Iteration 0, Testing (#0)
I0922 16:14:14.933842  2057 abc.cpp:176] Test score #0: 0.146329
I0914 17:37:15.763941 29832 abc.cpp:138] Iteration 1000, Testing (#0)
I0922 16:14:14.933842  2057 abc.cpp:176] Test score #0: 0.246222
I0914 17:37:15.763941 29832 abc.cpp:138] Iteration 2000, Testing (#0)
I0922 16:14:14.933842  2057 abc.cpp:176] Test score #0: 0.335429
I0914 17:37:15.763941 29832 abc.cpp:138] Iteration 3000, Testing (#0)
I0922 16:14:14.933842  2057 abc.cpp:176] Test score #0: 0.445429
I0914 17:37:15.763941 29832 abc.cpp:138] Iteration 4000, Testing (#0)
I0922 16:14:14.933842  2057 abc.cpp:176] Test score #0: 0.546429
```

and my question is how to get the number of iteration ( 0, 1000, 2000..., 4000) and test score ( 0.146329, 0.246222, 0.335429...., 0.546429) and combine them into dict.

For instance, my expected results are following:

```
dict = {'0':0.146329,
        '1000':0.246222
        '2000':0.335429
        '3000':0.445429
        '4000':0.546429}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fledgling I have already read file into "lines", and find the keyword(Iteration and score), something like score = [line for line in lines if "score" in line], iter = [line for line in lines if "Iteration" in line] to separate them, and then I have no idea to solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iter = 0
for line in file:
  itermatch = re.search('Iteration \d+',line)
  if itermatch:
    iter = itermatch.group()
  else:
    scorematch = re.search(': [0-9.]+',line)
    if scorematch:
      dict[iter]= scorematch.group()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it without using regular expressions:

```
result = {}
with open('test.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        data = line.strip().split('] ')[1]
        if ',' in data:
            key = data.split(',')[0]
            key = key.split(' ')[1]
        else:
            val = (data.split(':')[1]).strip()
            print val
            result[key] = val
```

This gives:

```
{'0': '0.146329',
 '1000': '0.246222',
 '2000': '0.335429',
 '3000': '0.445429',
 '4000': '0.546429'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=Iteration\s)(\d+)|(?<=Test score\s#0:\s)(\S+)
```

You can use this regex.Just grab the match and use it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/16